# GNUPlot Code for Plotting Three Dimensional Data

Tags: beginner, image, data-visualization

I am trying to plot three dimensional (multiple plane) data onto figures with various perspective view. The input data is tab-separated values in multiple file, and each file represent each plane. The document I referred is http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.4/Gnuplot_5_4.pdf .

An example is illustrated as below.

Plane1.txt

```
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1
```

Plane2.txt

```
0 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 0
```

Plane3.txt

```
2 0 2
0 2 0
2 0 2
```

Is there any possible improvement of this code?

```
do for [LoopNumber1=0:360] {
    dir = 'View'.LoopNumber1
    command1 = "mkdir " . dir
    system command1
    do for [LoopNumber2=0:360] {
        set term jpeg size 1280,1024
        set out dir.'/GNUPlotOutput'.LoopNumber2.'.jpeg'
        set grid
        set key off
        #set logscale cb
        set view LoopNumber1,LoopNumber2

        splot for [i=1:3] 'Plane'.i.'.txt' matrix using 1:2:(i):3 with point pointtype 5 pointsize 0.75 pal
    }
}
```

One of the plotting result is as below.

[image: PlottingResult]